# is anyone maintaining a haproxy 1.7 deb package?

Tags: debian, haproxy

haproxy 1.5 v17 handles ssl certificates.  from my use so far it's pretty stable.

is anyone maintaining a `.deb` for 1.7?  I am uniquely unqualified to do so.

Comment: Probably a better question to ask the Debian devs directly.

Comment: Seems pretty early for `1.7`, given that `1.5` is the dev release.   The latest I see in the official Debian repos is `1.4`.  Where are you finding this `1.7`?  If you have the source, and it isn't vastly different from the current release, you can often just reuse the current packaging meta-data with a newer version of the source.

Comment: @Zoredache - mean 17, not 1.7 - sorry.  17 has ssl support

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean 1.5, which is the development branch that includes SSL support.

http://www.roedie.nl/2012/12/28/haproxy-1-5-dev17/ supposedly has it, but your mileage may vary - keep in mind, deb packages are installed as root, so you should only install them from sources that you trust fully and explicitly.

You may also be able to use [Checkinstall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall) to build it yourself in a simpler fashion.